# windows - access "global" clipboard in c++ service

Tags: c++, windows, service, clipboard

I have a service written in C++ that needs to access the clipboard for the following tasks:

- Put data (`CF_TEXT`) on the clipboard, which should be visible to other applications so that it can be pasted there.
- Access any `CF_TEXT` type data posted to the clipboard by another application

I tried doing the above operations using the standard clipboard functions in C++, but I'm able to view data that I posted on the clipboard only within my service and not in other applications. The same goes for accessing data put by other applications on the clipboard.

How can I achieve what I described above? Is there any "global" clipboard so that this can be done?

**Note:** My service is running as `Local System`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [windows - access clipboard from service in c++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28718299/windows-access-clipboard-from-service-in-c)

Comment: This is the same question as before, with the same answer.  If you want to ask the question a different way, modify the original.